# Websocket без nodejs и прочей лабуды

Tags: php, websocket, javascript

Скажите, реально ли настроить Websocket соединение без использования различных библиотек и языков отличных от JS и PHP?

Почти в любом примере, что я видел, используют nodejs/ratchet/..., а мне не хочется переписывать почти всё из-за желания сделать динамическое обновление ленты новостей (похожее на ленту вконтакте), т.е. чтобы была возможность сообщить пользователю о новой новости и, после клика на появившуюся кнопку, эта новость ajax`ом подгрузилась.

Сейчас я реализовал это следующим образом: раз в N секунд отправляется ajax запрос, и сервер проверяет, есть ли новые новости, возвращает результат (если новость есть - показываем кнопку для загрузки новостей, если нет - то нет). Понятное дело, это отвратительное решение.

Может ли кто дать ссылку на реализацию чего-то более сложного, чем чат, связанного с Websocket на JS+PHP? Ну или подсказать, что можно ещё использовать, кроме websocket, для реализации задуманного, т.е. чтобы сервер сообщал о новых записях, а не клиент запрашивал всё.

Comment: эм... nodejs не отличается от js :)

а вообще можно, но сложно(проще на ноде написать), ищите асинхронные php сервера типа php-daemon. 

longpool (но тоже самое форкунутые апачи с modphp убъют ваш сервер)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С незапамятных времён у меня на диске хранился этот [файл](http://freetexthost.com/yccris5usr) (**>{gHf(Z[FAi\c№;KDR)!**).
Если коротко - юзай сокеты в бесконечном цикле.